# Too many legend items making it impossible to read

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, spatial

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with 213 Ecoregions to plot.
My issue is that I'm not able to organize the legend in a way that I could indeed read the legend. I'm new to r and I've been trying this for 2 days now, I feel really stupid... I wonder if anyone could give me some hint on how to achieve this goal.

```
#### Download and unzip ecoregions ####
#the reference for this ecoregions data: https://doi.org/10.1093/biosci/bix014

#Don't forget to change the path to a path of your own
dir_eco<-"C:/Users/thai/Desktop/Ecologicos/w2"


download.file("https://storage.googleapis.com/teow2016/Ecoregions2017.zip", 
              file.path(paste0(dir_eco,"/","Ecoregions2017.zip",sep=""))) 


unzip("Ecoregions2017.zip")

#Read this shapefile
#install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
ecoreg_shp<- readOGR("Ecoregions2017.shp")

#Crop to a smaller extent
xmin=-120; xmax=-35; ymin=-60; ymin2=-40; ymax=35
limits2 <- c(xmin, xmax, ymin2, ymax) # Just from mexico to Uruguay.
ecoreg_shp<-crop(ecoreg_shp,limits2)

# Color palette - one color for each attribute level
n <- 213
color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)] 
# pie(rep(1,n), col=sample(color, n)) #just to take a look at the colors
col_samp<-sample(color, n)
ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR<-col_samp #put the colors in the polygons data frame

#Plot
png(file="29_ecoreg2.png", width=3000, height=3000, units="px", res=300)
par(mar=c(50,0.3,1.5,0),pty="s")
spplot(ecoreg_shp, zcol = "ECO_NAME", col.regions = ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR, 
       colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 1))
dev.off()
```

Now, this is how this plot looks like:
[image: Ecoregions with messy legend]

I've managed to put this legend at the right of the map, but gets also too overlayed... I've tried to do `colorkey = FALSE` and set a separate `legend`...

```
#Plot the map with no legend
spplot(ecoreg_shp, zcol = "ECO_NAME", col.regions = ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR, 
       colorkey = FALSE)
#Now, just the legend
legend("bottom",legend=ecoreg_shp@data$ECO_NAME,fill=ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR, ncol=3)
```

But doesn't work.. I get a message that `plot.new has not been called yet`
 I've managed to do a lot of things with the legend, but I can't make it good... Like the legend item below the map in 2 or 3 columns in a long figure... Actually doesn't matter the format at all, I just wanted to be able to make a good figure. Can anyone point me in some direction? I'm trying to learn ggplot2, but I don't know r enough yet for using such a difficult package.
Thank you in advance, any tip is much appreciated.

Comment: As a general comment, you're not going to be able to make a sensible plot with 213 different colours/categories. There's probably only 6 or 7 colours which are distinct enough to make any kind of clear sense of in a plot. Normally you'd plot a map of an outcome (population density, rainfall etc) in each region, which would allow you to have a scale rather than discrete categories.

Comment: Do you really need to plot such a large area at one time? You need to decide on how granular the view needs to be. Consider multiple plots of smaller regions or aggregate them into larger groups.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to have 213 really distinct colors... But I need to present this map for an overall look, nobody will really check the places and the legend, but it must be there... I was planning to obtain the map and the legend and use photoshop to place them in the less terrible way... maybe a page with only the map and the next one with only the legends...

Comment: I second @thelatemail’s comment. A legend that isn’t legible is pointless. I’ve never seen a legend with more than maybe 10 discrete colors that I could map to the data. And I always try, because it’s something I care about. So don’t say “nobody will really check”. In general, in mapmaking it is acccepted to repeat colors when colors only serve to distinguish adjacent regions. If colors represent values, use a sequential color scale.

Comment: You are right, there is no shuch a thing as "nobody will check"... But in my case, the 213 levels are region names, they are not sequential values... Well... I will think in how to present this data.. Thank you guyfor the toughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, you will not really be able to distinguish between colors. You should define a classification with multiple levels and choose similar colors for similar ecoregions.
Nevertheless, you can create an image only for this long legend as follows. I used a reproducible example as I do not have your dataset but I use the same names as yours so that you can directly use the script:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

n <- 213

dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
ecoreg_shp <- readOGR(dsn = dsn, layer = "cities")
ecoreg_shp <- ecoreg_shp[1:n,]

# Color palette - one color for each attribute level
color <- grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)] 
col_samp <- sample(color, n)
ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR <- col_samp #put the colors in the polygons data frame
ecoreg_shp@data$ECO_NAME <- ecoreg_shp@data$NAME

# Define a grid to plot the legend
grid.dim <- c(45, 5)
ecoreg_shp@data$ROW <- rep(rev(1:grid.dim[1]), by = grid.dim[2], length.out = n)
ecoreg_shp@data$COL <- rep(1:grid.dim[2], each = grid.dim[1], length.out = n)

# Plot the legend
png(file = "legend.png",
    width = 21, height = 29.7,
    units = "cm", res = 300)
par(mai = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

plot(ecoreg_shp@data$COL,
     ecoreg_shp@data$ROW,
     pch = 22, cex = 2, 
     bg = ecoreg_shp@data$COLOR,
     xlim = c(0.8, grid.dim[2] + 1),
     xaxs = "i")
text(ecoreg_shp@data$COL,
     ecoreg_shp@data$ROW,
     ecoreg_shp@data$ECO_NAME, 
     pos = 4, cex = 0.75)

dev.off()
```

The result:
[image: colors and legends]

Comment: Sébastien, thank you very much! I'll use this grid thing that I learnt from you forever now! I found ou that my map is wrong (the polygons are not getting the color according to the color column...). But the legend code works perfectly. Thank you